# Buttons outside of carousel elements [react-multi-carousel]

Tags: reactjs, react-multi-carousel

Is it possible to make the arrows/buttons on the right and left sides be outside of the carousel items?

Links to the libarary:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-carousel
- https://w3js.com/react-multi-carousel

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always add **css** to the arrows

By default, left arrow has:

```
left: calc(4% + 1px);
```

and right arrow has:

```
right: calc(4% + 1px);
```

If you have space on the sides of carousel you can change that css.

Comment: I tried adding:
`
.react-multiple-carousel__arrow {
    right: 0;
}
`

Comment: However, this gets overwritten by the default value implemented in the library. How can I bypass it?

Comment: try with !important -> ` .react-multiple-carousel__arrow { right: 0 !important; } `

Comment: I'm trying this approach, but don't know if this can work. The arrows are within `react-multi-carousel`, which has `overflow: hidden;`. Because of this, the arrows won't be displayed

Comment: I managed to achieved it by giving proper margin and padding to the cards showing inside the `carousel`. But for me I just needed to show single card at a time in the `carousel` so not sure if this can work here also,

Answer (score 3):

Adding this to css file worked for me

```
.react-multi-carousel-list{
  position: unset !important;
}
```

React Code :

```
           <Carousel
                    swipeable={true}
                    draggable={true}
                    autoPlay={false}
                    showDots={true}
                    ssr={true}
                    renderDotsOutside={true}
                    arrows={true}
                    dotListClass={styles.carousel_dot}
                    responsive={responsive}
                  >
```

Answer (score 1):

THIS ONE IS WORK FOR ME!

1. you need to add wrapper to your Carousel.
2. set position relative to the wrapper.
3. set position unset to the carousel.
4. set position absolute to the arrow.

```css
.gd-carousel-wrapper {
    position:relative;

}

.gd-carousel {
    position:unset;

    .react-multiple-carousel__arrow {
        position:absolute;
    }

    .react-multiple-carousel__arrow--left {
        left: calc(-3% + 1px)
    }

    .react-multiple-carousel__arrow--right {
        right: calc(-3% + 1px)
    }
}
```

```html
`<div className="gd-carousel-wrapper">
    <Carousel
      responsive={responsive}
      // autoPlay={true}
      className="gd-carousel"
    >
    <div>Item1</div>
    <div>Item2</div>
    <div>Item3</div>
    <div>Item4</div>
    </Carousel>
 </div>`
```

Comment: Worked for me exactly as intended.